# Select the string columns which represents the MAX(DATE) of a group by? [Hive]

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a product table

```
Product Number |   Type   |   Code  |     Date
    P1-A            D          D1      2020-03-18
    P1-A            D          D2      2020-03-20 
    P1-A            D          D4      2020-03-29
    P1-A            P          P1      2020-01-20
    P1-A            P          P3A     2020-01-22
    P2-A            D          D1      2020-04-10
    P3-A           ...         ...        ...
```

I want to understand per group of `Product Number` and `Type` which is the MAX date of codes which are either [D2,D4] or [P3A,P4] and which code is representing the max date.

This code is wrong, but it shows my thinking

```
SELECT Product Number, MAX(D Code), MAX(D Date), MAX(P Code), MAX(P Date)  
FROM product_table WHERE code = 'D2' OR code = 'D4' or code = 'P3A' or code = 'P4'
GROUP BY Product Number, Type
```

The final table would look like

```
Product Number |   D Code  |  D Date    |   P Code   |   P Date   |
    P1-A            D4      2020-03-29       P3A       2020-01-22
    ...            ...          ...          ...          ...
    ....           ...          ...          ...          ...
```

How do I do this correctly using Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Product_Number, 
       max(case when type = 'D' then code end) as D_code,
       max(case when type = 'D' then date end) as D_date,
       max(case when type = 'P' then code end) as P_code,
       max(case when type = 'P' then date end) as P_date
  FROM product_table 
 WHERE code in('D2','D4','P3A','P4')
 GROUP BY Product_Number;
```

Comment: This is almost working correctly, I have now one row with P1-A | D4 | 2020-03-29 | NULL | NULL. And one row with P1-A |NULL | NULL |2020-01-22|P3A. How would I get it on the same line as shown in the question?

Comment: @kspr If you remove Type from group by, it will produce single line: `P1-A D4 2020-03-29 P3A 2020-01-22`. Is this what you want: https://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=111832

Comment: @kspr Edited answer